# Does it make sense to backpropagate a loss calculated from an earlier layer through the entire network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, pytorch

Suppose you have a neural network with 2 layers A and B. A gets the network input. A and B are consecutive (A's output is fed into B as input). Both A and B output predictions (prediction1 and prediction2) [Picture of the described architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQBQP.png)
You calculate a loss (loss1) directly after the first layer (A) with a target (target1). You also calculate a loss after the second layer (loss2) with its own target (target2).

Does it make sense to use the sum of loss1 and loss2 as the error function and back propagate this loss through the entire network? If so, why is it "allowed" to back propagate loss1 through B even though it has nothing to do with it?

This question is related to this question
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/37022/intuition-importance-of-intermediate-supervision-in-deep-learning
but it does not answer my question sufficiently.
In my case, A and B are unrelated modules. In the aforementioned question, A and B would be identical. The targets would be the same, too.

(Additional information)
The reason why I'm asking is that I'm trying to understand LCNN (https://github.com/zhou13/lcnn) from this [paper](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_ICCV_2019/papers/Zhou_End-to-End_Wireframe_Parsing_ICCV_2019_paper.pdf).
LCNN is made up of an Hourglass backbone, which then gets fed into MultiTask Learner (creates [loss1](https://github.com/zhou13/lcnn/blob/88f281ab5421d51a62f1f84f97fea05afbf0c8d8/lcnn/models/multitask_learner.py#L89)), which in turn gets fed into a LineVectorizer Module ([loss2](https://github.com/zhou13/lcnn/blob/88f281ab5421d51a62f1f84f97fea05afbf0c8d8/lcnn/models/line_vectorizer.py#L144)). Both loss1 and loss2 are then summed up [here](https://github.com/zhou13/lcnn/blob/88f281ab5421d51a62f1f84f97fea05afbf0c8d8/lcnn/trainer.py#L88) and then back propagated through the entire network [here](https://github.com/zhou13/lcnn/blob/88f281ab5421d51a62f1f84f97fea05afbf0c8d8/lcnn/trainer.py#L183).

Even though I've visited several deep learning lectures, I didn't know this was "allowed" or makes sense to do. I would have expected to use two `loss.backward()`, one for each loss. Or is the pytorch computational graph doing something magical here? LCNN converges and outperforms other neural networks which try to solve the same task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes, It is "allowed" and also makes sense.

From the question, I believe you have understood most of it so I'm not going to details about why this multi-loss architecture can be useful. I think the main part that has made you confused is **why does "loss1" back-propagate through "B"?** and the answer is: **It doesn't**. The fact is that loss1 is calculated using this formula:

```
loss1 = SOME_FUNCTION(label, y_hat)
```

and `y_hat`(prediction1) is only dependent on layers before it. Hence, the gradient of this loss only flows through layers before this section (A) and not the ones after it (B). To better understand this, you could again check the [mathematics of artificial neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_artificial_neural_networks).  The loss2, on the other hand, back-propagates through all of the network (including part A). When you use a cumulative loss (`Loss = loss1 + loss2`), a framework like Pytorch will automatically follow the gradient of every predicted label to the first layer.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer together with this video explaining pytorch autograd (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MswxJw-8PvE) helped me understand it. For those wondering: When doing the sum of loss1 and loss2 pytorch autograd will remember where the elements of the sum came from. When then calling the backward function on the loss it will traverse all of its parts and individually follow it and calculate the gradients. Whats important to remember from this is that when calculating the loss you should always use your frameworks tensor as it does some bookkeeping in the background.